# Energy-minimizing set of discrete points in a bounded domain

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, physics, potential-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth, bounded domain. 
Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \overline{\Omega}$ be chosen so as to minimize
$$
\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \frac{1}{|y_i - y_j|}
$$
over all possible choices of $y_1,\ldots,y_n \in \overline\Omega$.

Is it then true that $\min \{|x_i - x_j| : 1\leq i < j \leq n \}$ equals the maximum of $\min\{|y_i - y_j| : 1\leq i < j \leq n\}$ over all possible choices of $y_1,\ldots,y_n \in \overline\Omega$?

I know this is related to Fekete points and the Thomson problem.  Maybe it's easy.  References are appreciated as well.

Comment: Have you looked at the case of $4$ or more points on an interval of length $1$ (the limiting case of thin parallelepipeds). There the configuration maximizing the minimal distance between points is unique and it is a simple exercise in calculus to check if it is stationary for the energy functional.

Comment: I very much doubt. In the limit as $n$ goes to infinity, and after appropriate re-scaling, this should converge to the Newtonian capacity of $\Omega$: the minimal Newtonian energy of a probability measure supported on $\Omega$. The minimizing measure (a.k.a. *equilibrium measure*) is known to be concentrated on $\partial \Omega$, so I suspect for large $n$ the points will tend to concentrate on the boundary.

Comment: The answer is "no", by the example suggested by @fedja. For the segment, the $\max \min |y_i-y_j|$ is achieved for uniform distribution while the extremal configuration for the Newton energy is not uniform.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko (and @fedja) Even though the segment is not smooth or open?

Comment: I realize the idea would be to represent the segment as a limit of smooth domains, i.e. letting $\epsilon$ go to zero in $\{x^2 + (y/\epsilon)^2 + (z/\epsilon)^2 <1\}$.
And it is not obvious to me why the extremal configuration for the Newton energy should not be uniform.

Comment: @Ben Cioti: by a segment I mean a straight line segment. Of course it is not open, but you can approximate it by a thin cylinder.

Comment: @Ben Cioti: strictly speaking extremal charge for the segment does not exist (a segment has zero capacity). Nevertheless it seems evident to me that the extremal charge of a thin cylinder is not uniform, and this can be confirmed by a rigorous computation. The charge will be more dense near the ends.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Wow, you've got good intuition. For what it's worth, I did a calculation to find the minimizing configuration for 4 electrons on a segment of length 3.  The uniform distribution would be for charges at positions 0, 1, 2 and 3 units along the segment, while the energy minimizing configuration had them at 0, .9, 2.1, and 3 (approximately).  So pretty close but not exactly uniform, in agreement with intuition.

Comment: @Ben Ciotti: if you take more points it will be further from uniform (the points will tend to concentrate near the ends).